# Transient members in flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am just starting with flink Please help in understand the basics of transient members in flink.
I want to understand about working of transient in Flink.
As per my understanding in order to distribute the job across cluster flink serialize the operators except the members declared as transient will not be serialized ?
If they are not serialized then how they are distributed because we need to convert them to bytes inorder to transmit across the network ?
Why do we serializing the operator itself ? If it is possible can't we send it as it is  without serializing them?

Answer (score 0):

Any members marked as `transient` should be initialized in the `open()` method, which is called before event processing begins.